# Why Visual Studio generates two versions of Obj?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I use `Visual studio 2010` to compile a solution. An error is reported that

> The object or library file ... was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries.

Then I disable `/GL` on the concerned lib project as workaround, but another error is reported that

> Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20100826' and 'P2' version '20081201'

I checked framework and platformtoolset, all projects are same (4.0 & v100). How visual studio compiled two versions of obj? Any good way to remove this compile error?

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the whole solution as suggested?

Comment: Yes, I try to rebuild but the error is still reported. I am thinking there are any way I can check on which version of VS an .obj is compiled?

Comment: Are you statically linking an old .lib file or compiling the source code and generating them? I think, you are not cleaning up old library files and generating them again by compilation.

Comment: Just remove all the obj folder and rebuild again.the problem still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have changed the configuration of the project. Changed path names are a good candidates. Consider these steps

- Clean the project from the Visual Studio menu
- Delete any .obj file from the Windows Explorer
- Build again.

If this doesn't help, enable verbose linker output and check what files are actually linked.